# Google App Engine self.redirect() POST method

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In GAE (Python), using the webApp Framework, calling self.redirect('some_url') redirects the user to that URL via the GET method. Is it possible to do a (redirect) via the POST method with some parameters as well?

If possible, how?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really an issue with App Engine; a web browser won't do a POST in response to a 3xx HTTP status.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible due to how most clients implement redirection [1]:

> However, most existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it
>   were a 303 response, performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless
>   of the original request method.

So you must use a workaround (like simply calling the method post() from the RequestHandler) or forget the idea.

[1] http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2

Comment: The problem with calling the post() method on the RequestHandler is that if you want to post to a url that uses a different RequestHandler, there's no way to do that.  Ie: say you're in the RequestHandler for "/main" and you want to POST to "/dev", you can't do that from the RequestHandler for "/main".  Or at least if there is, I'm not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** pass parameters. Here is an example:

Let's say you have a main page and you want to POST to '/success'. Usually, you may use this way:

`self.redirect('/sucess')`

But if you want to pass some parameters from the main page to `/success` page, like `username` for example, you can modify the code to this:

`self.redirect('/sucess?username=' + username)`

In this way, you successfully passed the `username` value into the URL. In `/success` page, you can read and store the value by using this:

`username = self.request.get('username')`

At last, you can make you favorite information onto the `/success` page by using this simple code:

`self.response.out.write('You\'ve succeeded, ' + username + '!')`

**But**, it's of course not a safe way to pass password. I wish it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like there's a similar question asked here: [Google App Engine self.redirect post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881086/google-app-engine-self-redirect-post)

The answer to that one recommends using the urlfetch.fetch() to do the post.

```
import urllib

form_fields = {
  "first_name": "Albert",
  "last_name": "Johnson",
  "email_address": "Albert.Johnson@example.com"
}
form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
                        payload=form_data,
                        method=urlfetch.POST,
                        headers=headers)
```

Comment: If you're posting data to yourself, that's a pretty good sign that you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: The problem with this too is that if the url you're POSTing to is in your GAE app, then when running locally it will hang (the dev_appserver is single threaded).

Comment: @NickJohnson: why is it such a bad thing? (genuinely curious)

Comment: @AdamParkin Because you have full control over your own app - there's no reason to make this roundabout trip via HTTP when you could just invoke the relevant functionality directly.

Comment: Sure, fair enough, I just wasn't sure if there was some sort of security issue with POSTing to oneself. Thanks.