# Python sending and receiving HTTP POST

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http, post

I am in the process of learning Python and I am trying to do something really simple: send an HTTP POST from one application and receive it in the other, not only I can't get it to work, I can't get it to work with what would seem reasonable, using def post(self). This is the code I have, which doesn't give errors, but doesn't do the task either:
Sender Application:

```
import cgi
import webapp2
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

senddata = {}
senddata["message"] = 'Testing the Sender'


class MainPagePost(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        txt_url_values = urllib.urlencode(senddata)
        txturl = 'http://localhost:10080'
        result = urllib.urlopen(txturl, txt_url_values)
        self.redirect('http://localhost:10080') 

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPagePost), 
], debug=True)
```

Recieving Application:

```
import cgi
import webapp2
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class MainPageGet(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.write('you sent:')
        con = self.request.get("message")
        self.response.write(con)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPageGet), 
], debug=True)
```

All I get on the localhost is "you sent:" :(
Worst of all I don't understand why both defs need to be "get(self)" so that I don't get 405 error...
Thanks all :)

This is the "new" code, for the sender no change:

```
import cgi
import webapp2
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

senddata = {}
senddata["message"] = 'Testing Tester'


class MainPagePost(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        txt_url_values = urllib.urlencode(senddata)
        txturl = 'http://localhost:10080'
        result = urllib.urlopen(txturl, txt_url_values)
        self.redirect('http://localhost:10080') 

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPagePost), 
], debug=True)
```

The receiver I changed to post, as Sam suggested, but I am getting 405:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cgi
import webapp2
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class MainPageGet(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        # self.response.write('you sent:')
        con = self.request.get("message")
        self.response.write('you sent: ' + con)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPageGet), 
], debug=True)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you would like app-1 to respond to GET requests by sending a POST request to app-2 and sending back its response. Also, providing `localhost` to `urlopen` suggests testing locally only.

Assuming you want this in production, I'd suggest the following:
The application listening to POST requests is fine. The application listening to GET requests requires a few changes. The url should be a public one where your POST application is deployed. Instead of `self.redirect()`, simply `self.response.write(result)` and you should get the response from the POST application.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [example](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html):

```
self.response.write("<html><body><p>Hi there!</p></body></html>")
```

> The response buffers all output in memory, then sends the final output when the handler exits. webapp2 does not support streaming data to the client.

so basically, response.write must be the last thing you call:

```
def get(self):            
        con = self.request.get("message")
        self.response.write("you sent: " + con )
```

Also, I suggest you check this [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms) to read more about POST and GET requests with forms on Appengine. I don't understand what you're trying to do with those two views, but they clash with each other

Comment: Hey Sam, I've read all those links and more :( and it still doesn't "click". I am trying to do something very simple: to POST senddata to localhost and receive it and show it. First thing I don't understand is why "def get(self)" works, I am trying to POST, shouldn't it be "def post(self)"? Second thing is, ok since it has to be "def get(self)" so that I don't get errors, why doesn't it show the data? I've tried your suggestion of merging the two .write into one and I am getting a page with only "you sent:" on it... :(

Comment: the `POST` method kicks in if there's been a real post request, otherwise the request will be handled by the `GET`, that's why for you it doesn't work: you have no post method defined

Comment: hmm... I want to define a post :( the sender program should be posting to the receiver...but if I change the get to post I get 405...

Comment: the view receiving the post data should be the one with `def post(self):` defined (405 Not Allowed means you didn't define the method you're trying to use, which in your case is the post) update your OP with the correct non-working post code plz, you may be missing out some tiny typo or something else

Comment: :) so the sender program should be a get? wierd! :) I added the "new" code to the OP

Comment: the main thing is that you're not sending a post on your sender view. you should use a form (rendered in your get view) or follow this http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#post-data

Comment: Using the html form I had it working before too. The problem is that, I know less of html than I know of python :( (if possible!) Isn't there a way to do this without html, especially since the data I send I need to manipulate it first and then post out the answer. In all the various combinations I've tried of different instructions, I had it working once! Unfortunately I changed something since then and I broke it, and since I don't understand how it works I can't reproduce it :(

Comment: Forget my lousy code for a moment. This is what I am trying to accomplish: create a list of variables(senddata) send it using HTTP POST to a different application. There I do my thing(already coded and works). I package the answer in another POST and send it to a third application and show it on the screen...

Comment: The first POST request will need a response, and you *could* have it wait for the second POST (sent via UrlFetch to the second server) to complete and return, finally returning it all back to the "screen" of the client. But this makes the system prone to failure and sensitive to latency. I suggest having the first server give a unique ID back to the client, which it can then use to request the final result once it has been persisted somewhere by the second server (this also allows you to close the connections quickly).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie too. Learning Python from last weekend and your question has been a reference for my learning.

## The sending app

============================

```
import webapp2
import urllib
import urllib2
import json
import os
import random
import time
i=0


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        url = "http://localhost:12080/"


        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        html_string = response.read()
        self.response.write(html_string)
        self.response.write(os.environ.get("HTTP_USER_AGENT", "N/A"))
        self.response.write(random.uniform(1,10))

        """


        while True:
            self.post()
            global i
            i+=1
            time.sleep(2)

        """




    def post(self):

        url = "http://localhost:12080/receive"

        name = random.uniform(1,10)
        post_data_dictionary = {'name':str(name), "age":i, "favorite OS":"Ubuntu"}
        http_headers = {'User-Agent':'OWN'}
        post_data_encoded = urllib.urlencode(post_data_dictionary)
        request_object = urllib2.Request(url, post_data_encoded,http_headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request_object)



app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

## The receiving app

```
import webapp2

import cgi
import webapp2
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext import db
import os

class Message(db.Model):
    msg=db.StringProperty()
    #user_agent=db.StringProperty()
    age=db.StringProperty()
    fOS=db.StringProperty()
    useragent=db.StringProperty()


class Receive(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    #def get(self):
        #self.response.write('Rececive!')
        #self.post()

    def post(self):
        var1 = self.request.get("name")
        var2 = self.request.get("age")
        var3 = self.request.get("favorite OS")
        var4 = os.environ.get("HTTP_USER_AGENT")





        mes=Message()
        mes.msg=var1
        mes.age=var2
        mes.useragent=var4
        mes.fOS=var3



        mes.put()
        #self.response.write('you sent: ' + con)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        #req=datastore.RunQueryRequest()
        #gql_query= req.gql_query

        self.response.write(os.environ.get("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))








        #a=Message()







app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/receive', Receive)
        ], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last comments mentions 3 points of contact:

- `application-1` responding to GET requests POSTing to
  `application-2`
- `application-2` responding to POST requests POSTing
  to `application-3`
- `application-3` responding to POST requests
  showing responses to screen

If you must have all the work and message passing take place on the server side, I would suggest using App Engine's [URL Fetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) service from `application-1` to issue a `POST` request to `application-2` followed by a `POST` request to `application-3`. This is because you cannot reliably redirect from `application-2` to `application-3` with a server-initiated `POST` request based on how [most browsers implement redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3600997/5317173).

### Server-side example

```
# Application 1
import webapp2
import urllib
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

url_app_2 = 'http://application-2.com/'
url_app_3 = 'http://application-3.com/'

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    data_to_post = {
      'message': 'Important data to pass on'
    }
    encoded_data = urllib.urlencode(data_to_post)
    # Send encoded data to application-2
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url_app_2, encoded_data, method='POST')

    data_to_post = {
      'message': result.content
    }
    encoded_data = urllib.urlencode(data_to_post)
    # Send encoded application-2 response to application-3
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url_app_3, encoded_data, method='POST')

    # Output response of application-3 to screen
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.write(result.content)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)


# Application 2
import webapp2

response_template = 'The message sent was:\n{0}'

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    message = self.request.get('message')
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.write(response_template.format(message))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)


# Application 3
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    message = self.request.get('message')
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.write(message)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

The major downside to this is the initial GET request will not receive a response until both sequential POST requests have returned. This risks high response times.

### Client side example

This version could be accomplished using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) from the client. The advantage here is that the client gets an immediate response from the initial `GET` request while the subsequent `POST` requests are treated in the client's browser. `application-2` and `application-3` should serve responses in the same way. Only `application-1` changes and would simply need to serve the following HTML and Javascript to the client as in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/eb5wuxzf/1/).